# Why normal r.squared and fitted values are not the same when computed manually?

Tags: r, regression

I am wondering if the computed `R-squared` from `lm` would be the same if you compute the predictions and then calculate `R and square it` between them and the original values (to be predicted). In my case here they are different.
the model is:

```
log(y) = alog(1+x1)+blog(1+x2)+c
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,NA,5,5,6);x1 <- log(x1) 
x2 <- c(0.9,0.4,0.8,4,NA,3,4,6);x2 <- log(x2) 
y  <- c(1.6,4.4,5.5,8.3,3,NA,7,3) 
y2 = log(y)
fm1 <- lm(y2 ~ x1+x2)
> summary(fm1)
Call:
lm(formula = y2 ~ x1 + x2)

Residuals:
        1         2         3         4         7         8 
-0.147261 -0.029340  0.008704  0.612128  0.229587 -0.673819 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.5868     0.5551   1.057    0.368
x1            0.9509     0.5871   1.620    0.204
x2           -0.2892     0.3517  -0.822    0.471

Residual standard error: 0.549 on 3 degrees of freedom
(2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.5079,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1799 
F-statistic: 1.548 on 2 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.3452
```

Now lets compare the correlations:

```
> y1= exp((0.9509*x1)+ (-0.2892 * x2) +(0.5868))
> cor(y1,y, use="na.or.complete", method="pearson")
[1] 0.4813884
> (0.4813884)^2
[1] 0.2317348
```

You can see here the values are different!

```
> y1
[1] 1.647246 2.600102 2.838444 2.381542       NA 2.792149 2.639814 2.655218
> fitted(fm2)
       1        2        3        4        7        8 
0.661362 1.471144 1.751985 1.450974 1.728920 1.752749
```

Comment: I didn't get past the fact that your `x1` and `x2` are identical, so the fitting should throw out one as collinear. Otherwise you seem to be comparing correlations and $R^2$.

Comment: sorry I pasted the wrong data,but they should be:`x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,NA,5,5,6) 
x1 <- log(1+x1) 
x2 <- c(0.9,0.4,0.8,4,NA,3,4,6)
x2 <- log(1+x2) 
y <- c(1.6,4.4,5.5,8.3,3,NA,7,3)`

Comment: hyat = sim??? Please merge your accounts. Could you clean up the post then? Also, the existence of NAs is just a distraction here. Post a worked example with commentary. Also, many people here do not use R, so please focus on the statistics of your question.

Comment: The fallacy here is that the correlation between $y$ and $\hat y$ should be equal to that between $y$ and $\exp(\hat y)$. Also, you are confusing yourself: you replace `x1` with `log(1 + x1)` and similarly `x2`, so you don't need to do that calculation again.

Answer (score 4):

In the bivariate case,it would be the same as calculating the correlation between your predictor and your outcome (not the predicted values), but  this is more complicated with more than one predictor in your model. Let's take an example with a small amount of data. First, the simple bivariate case in which y is predicted by x:

```
x<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y<- 4 + .2*x - 3*y + rnorm(6)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
      1       2       3       4       5       6 
    -2.7744  3.6449 -3.2407  4.0280  0.9585 -2.6162 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -3.4765     3.4669  -1.003    0.373
x            -0.1860     0.8902  -0.209    0.845

Residual standard error: 3.724 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0108,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2365 
F-statistic: 0.04365 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.8447
```

Here we get an $R^2 $ of .0108. Taking the square root of this value is the same as the Pearson's correlation coefficient.

```
> sqrt(.0108)
[1] 0.103923
> cor(x,y)
[1] -0.1039008
```

The difference we see in values has to be due to rounding. Your case includes 2 predictors so let's add an additional predictor variable:

```
z <- c(3,2,4,1,3,4)
```

The result of the lm():

Call:
    lm(formula = y ~ x + z)

```
Residuals:
      1       2       3       4       5       6 
-1.3542  1.9666  0.1159 -1.1361  0.8294 -0.4215 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   2.8495     2.1165   1.346   0.2709  
x             0.2013     0.3977   0.506   0.6476  
z            -2.7111     0.6365  -4.259   0.0237 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.62 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8596,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7661 
F-statistic: 9.187 on 2 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.05258
```

Although it isn't something I have personally come across in my own data analysis adventures, http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/multiple-correlation/, gives the formula for a multiple correlation coefficient as:

$$ \sqrt{\frac {r_{xy}^2 + r_{zy}^2 - 2r_{xy}^2r_{zy}^2r_{xz}^2}{1-r_{xz}^2}} $$

By plugging in the correlation coefficients:

```
corrxy<- cor(x,y)
corryz<- cor(y,z)
corrxz<-cor(x,z)
sqrt((corrxy^2 + corryz^2 - 2*corrxy* corryz*corrxz)/(1-corrxz^2))

> sqrt((corrxy^2 + corryz^2 - 2*corrxy* corryz*corrxz)/(1-corrxz^2))
[1] 0.9275252
> sqrt(.8596)
[1] 0.9271462
```

These two values are not exactly the same and I think this is likely because of some rounding issue, but they are quite close. I am not certain what math you are doing to come up with a multivariate correlation coefficient, or what you mean by using the predicted values to obtain this number, but if you correctly calculate the correlation coefficient for three variables it should match with the the square root of the $R^2$ associated with the omnibus, 2 df, test. Hope this helps!